# Implementing negative exponents with arbitrary-precision integers?

Tags: math, data-structures, exponential, decimal-point

I'm trying to make a calculator using arbitrary-precision maths but I can't figure out how to handle negative exponents. 
What is the most efficient way to preform an operation involving n**-x?
So far i've tried 1/n**x, the problem is that I have no way of knowing how many numbers will trail the decimal point and using integers for example defeats the purpose of making a calculator using arbitrary-precision as it would restrict the size of the allowed input numbers. I was wondering if there is any other way to do this.

I'm programming in C but any method for negative exponents works honestly.

Comment: What does this have to do with linked-lists?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your calculator uses linked lists? Is this to store arbitrary-precision integers?

Comment: each node of the list holds a digit of the numbers being operated, yes, I forgot to mention it is arbitrary-precision, however I do need the exact result if I were to convert from binary to decimal so I can later add it to another power of 2**-x

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support arbitrary-precision arithmetic with negative exponents, it sounds like you might want to consider storing your number as a fraction in simplest form with the numerator and denominator each storing arbitrary-precision integers. To implement something like x<sup>-n</sup> where x = a / b, you'd end up with the number b<sup>n</sup> / a<sup>n</sup>. This way, you don't need to worry about decimal digits at all, which is a good thing because most real numbers don't have finite decimal representations.

Comment: it sounds like I could use this however i'm a bit confused as to what b is could you maybe give an example using actual numbers?

Comment: Sure! Suppose you want to store the number 5. Instead, store 5 / 1. Then, to compute 5^-3, you can store 1 / 5^3 = 1 / 125.

Comment: that definitely puts me on the right track, thank you